# Can someone explain to me why I would need functional programming instead of OOP?

Tags: oop, programming-languages, functional-programming, paradigms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Functional programming vs Object Oriented programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078978/functional-programming-vs-object-oriented-programming)

Can someone explain to me why I would need functional programming instead of OOP?

E.g. why would I need to use Haskell instead of C++ (or a similar language)?

**What are the advantages of functional programming over OOP?**

Comment: You don't *need* to use one or the other. There are different ways to arrive at the same goal. It's largely a matter of preference, with consideration of the particular problem you're trying to solve. Do you mean "what are the **advantages** of functional programming over OOP?"

Comment: yes, i can add the question: what are the advantages of functional programming over OOP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Functional programming vs Object Oriented programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078978/functional-programming-vs-object-oriented-programming). Also see: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552336/oop-vs-functional-programming-vs-procedural](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552336/oop-vs-functional-programming-vs-procedural).

Comment: This question is asked like once every other week. Use the search function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the big things I prefer in functional programming is the lack of "spooky action at a distance".  What you see is what you get – and no more.  This makes code far easier to reason about.

Let's use a simple example.  Let's say I come across the code snippet `X = 10` in either Java (OOP) or Erlang (functional).  In Erlang I can know these things very quickly:

1. The variable `X` is in the immediate context I'm in.  Period.  It's either a parameter passed in to the function I'm reading or it's being assigned the first (and only—c.f. below) time.
2. The variable `X` has a value of 10 from this point onward.  It will not change again within the block of code I'm reading.  It cannot.

In Java it's more complicated:

1. The variable `X` might be defined as a parameter.
2. It might be defined somewhere else in the method.
3. It might be defined as part of the class the method is in.
4. Whatever the case is, since I'm not declaring it here, I'm changing its value.  This means I don't know what the value of `X` will be without constantly scanning backward through the code to find the last place it was assigned or modified explicitly or implicitly (like in a for loop).
5. When I call another method, if `X` happens to be a class variable it may change out from underneath me with no way for me to know this without inspecting the code of that method.
6. In the context of a threading program it's even worse.  `X` can be changed by something I can't even see in my immediate environment.  Another thread may be calling the method in #5 that modifies `X`.

And Java is a relatively **simple** OOP language.  The number of ways that `X` can be screwed around with in C++ is even higher and potentially more obscure.

And the thing is?  This is just a *simple* example of how a common operation can be far more complicated in an OOP (or other imperative) language than in a functional.  It also doesn't address the benefits of functional programming that don't involve mutable state, etc. like higher order functions.

Answer (score 5):

There are three things about Haskell that I think are really cool:

1) It's a statically-typed language that is extremely expressive and lets you build highly maintainable and refactorable code quickly.  There's been a big debate between statically typed languages like Java and C# and dynamic languages like Python and Ruby.  Python and Ruby let you quickly build programs, using only a fraction of the number of lines required in a language like Java or C#.  So, if your goal is to get to market quickly, Python and Ruby are good choices.  But, because they're dynamic, refactoring and maintaining your code is tough.  In Java, if you want to add a parameter to a method, it's easy to use the IDE to find all instances of the method and fix them.  And if you miss one, the compiler catches it.  With Python and Ruby, refactoring mistakes will only be caught as run-time errors.  So, with traditional languages, you get to choose between quick development and lousy maintainability on the one hand and slow development and good maintainability on the other hand.  Neither choice is very good.

But with Haskell, you don't have to make this type of choice.  Haskell is statically typed, just like Java and C#.  So, you get all the refactorability, potential for IDE support, and compile-time checking.  But at the same time, types can be inferred by the compiler.  So, they don't get in your way like they do with traditional static languages.  Plus, the language offers many other features that allow you to accomplish a lot with only a few lines of code.  So, you get the speed of development of Python and Ruby along with the safety of static languages.

2) Parallelism.  Because functions don't have side effects, it's much easier for the compiler to run things in parallel without much work from you as a developer.  Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
a = f x
b = g y
c = h a b
```

In a pure functional language, we know that functions f and g have no side effects.  So, there's no reason that f has to be run before g.  The order could be swapped, or they could be run at the same time.  In fact, we really don't have to run f and g at all until their values are needed in function h.  This is not true in a traditional language since the calls to f and g could have side effects that could require us to run them in a particular order.

As computers get more and more cores on them, functional programming becomes more important because it allows the programmer to easily take advantage of the available parallelism.

3) The final really cool thing about Haskell is also possibly the most subtle: lazy evaluation.  To understand this, consider the problem of writing a program that reads a text file and prints out the number of occurrences of the word "the" on each line of the file.  Suppose you're writing in a traditional imperative language.

Attempt 1: You write a function that opens the file and reads it one line at a time.  For each line, you calculate the number of "the's", and you print it out.  That's great, except your main logic (counting the words) is tightly coupled with your input and output.  Suppose you want to use that same logic in some other context?  Suppose you want to read text data off a socket and count the words?  Or you want to read the text from a UI?  You'll have to rewrite your logic all over again!

Worst of all, what if you want to write an automated test for your new code?  You'll have to build input files, run your code, capture the output, and then compare the output against your expected results.  That's do-able, but it's painful.  Generally, when you tightly couple IO with logic, it becomes really difficult to test the logic.

Attempt 2: So, let's decouple IO and logic.  First, read the entire file into a big string in memory.  Then, pass the string to a function that breaks the string into lines, counts the "the's" on each line, and returns a list of counts.  Finally, the program can loop through the counts and output them.  It's now easy to test the core logic since it involves no IO.  It's now easy to use the core logic with data from a file or from a socket or from a UI.  So, this is a great solution, right?

Wrong.  What if someone passes in a 100GB file?  You'll blow out your memory since the entire file must be loaded into a string.

Attempt 3: Build an abstraction around reading the file and producing results.  You can think of these abstractions as two interfaces.  The first has methods nextLine() and done().  The second has outputCount().  Your main program implements nextLine() and done() to read from the file, while outputCount() just directly prints out the count.  This allows your main program to run in constant memory.  Your test program can use an alternate implementation of this abstraction that has nextLine() and done() pull test data from memory, while outputCount() checks the results rather than outputting them.

This third attempt works well at separating the logic and the IO, and it allows your program to run in constant memory.  But, it's significantly more complicated than the first two attempts.

In short, traditional imperative languages (whether static or dynamic) frequently leave developers making a choice between

a) Tight coupling of IO and logic (hard to test and reuse)

b) Load everything into memory (not very efficient)

c) Building abstractions (complicated, and it slows down implementation)

These choices come up when reading files, querying databases, reading sockets, etc.  More often than not, programmers seem to favor option A, and unit tests suffer as a consequence.

So, how does Haskell help with this?  In Haskell, you would solve this problem exactly like in Attempt 2.  The main program loads the whole file into a string.  Then it calls a function that examines the string and returns a list of counts.  Then the main program prints the counts.  It's super easy to test and reuse the core logic since it's isolated from the IO.

But what about memory usage?  Haskell's lazy evaluation takes care of that for you.  So, even though your code looks like it loaded the whole file contents into a string variable, the whole contents really aren't loaded.  Instead, the file is only read as the string is consumed.  This allows it to be read one buffer at a time, and your program will in fact run in constant memory.  That is, you can run this program on a 100GB file, and it will consume very little memory.

Similarly, you can query a database, build a resulting list containing a huge set of rows, and pass it to a function to process.  The processing function has no idea that the rows came from a database.  So, it's decoupled from its IO.  And under-the-covers, the list of rows will be fetched lazily and efficiently.  So, even though it looks like it when you look at your code, the full list of rows is never all in memory at the same time.

End result, you can test your function that processes the database rows without even having to connect to a database at all.

Lazy evaluation is really subtle, and it takes a while to get your head around its power.  But, it allows you to write nice simple code that is easy to test and reuse.

Here's the final Haskell solution and the Approach 3 Java solution.  Both use constant memory and separate IO from processing so that testing and reuse are easy.

Haskell:

```
module Main
    where

import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.Char (toLower)

main = do
  (fileName : _) <- getArgs
  fileContents <- readFile fileName
  mapM_ (putStrLn . show) $ getWordCounts fileContents

getWordCounts = (map countThe) . lines . map toLower
    where countThe = length . filter (== "the") . words
```

Java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;

class CountWords {
    public interface OutputHandler {
        void handle(int count) throws Exception;
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0])));

            OutputHandler handler = new OutputHandler() {
                public void handle(int count) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
            };

            countThe(reader, handler);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) reader.close();
        }
    }

    static public void countThe(BufferedReader reader, OutputHandler handler) throws Exception {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            int num = 0;
            for (String word: line.toLowerCase().split("([.,!?:;'\"-]|\\s)+")) {
                if (word.equals("the")) {
                    num += 1;
                }
            }
            handler.handle(num);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing lazy evaluation with lazy IO. The two are different things, and while lazy IO is great in your example, it can also byte you - for instance if you try to read from a file that has already been closed. You correctly describe lazy evaluation when you say `In fact, we really don't have to run f and g at all until their values are needed in function h.`

Answer (score 1):

If we compare Haskell and C++, functional programming makes debugging extremely easy, because there's no mutable state and variables like ones found in C, Python etc. which you should always care about, and it's ensured that, given some arguments, a function will always return the same results in spite the number of times you evaluate it.

OOP is orthogonal to any programming paradigm, and there are lanugages which combine FP with OOP, [OCaml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective_Caml) being the most popular, [several Haskell implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29#Related_languages) etc.

Comment: Well yeah, I mean if someone were to write a program using global variables in C++, it might be hard to debug. Fortunately, you don't do that in OOP, either. No win for functional there; that's just bad C with classes.

Comment: I'd +1 your answer if you replace "global state" with "mutable state".  It's quite possible to program without global state in OOP languages (and indeed some of them force this).  But the global nature of the state is not the main problem.  It's the fact that the state can change that makes it a problem.