# Reducing the number of arguments in function in Python?

Tags: python, function, arguments

My question is about how to deal with the piece of code where I am using the **Caesar´s cipher**.

Functions Decrypt and Encrypt have to deal with the limits of the alphabet **(A - Z and a - z)**. I tried to write the two possible cycles for both alphabets in one cycle function named **cycleencrypt**.

But the function takes about **6 arguments** and I have read somewhere that is less readable and understandable having more than **3 arguments** in one function so my question is:

Should I **reduce the number of arguments** by splitting in two functions and make the piece of code longer (but maybe more understandable)?
Thanks for any answer I aprreciate that.

EDIT:  Docstrings around the functions were deleted to make visible the
       main purpose of my question.

```
def offsetctrl(offset):
    while offset < 0:
        offset += 26
    return offset

def cycleencrypt(string, offset, index, listing, first, last):
    offset = offsetctrl(offset)
    if string >= ord(first) and string <= ord(last):
        string += offset
        while string > ord(last):
            string = ord(first) + (string - ord(last) -1)
        listing[index] = chr(string)
```

Cycle for encrypting with a **lots of arguments** and control of negative offset´s

```
def encrypt(retezec, offset):
    listing = list(retezec)
    for index in range(0, len(retezec)):
        string = ord(retezec[index])
        cycleencrypt(string, offset, index, listing, 'A', 'Z')
        cycleencrypt(string, offset, index, listing, 'a', 'z')
    print(''.join(listing))
```

main encryption part taking **many arguments** in two lines with printing

```
def decrypt(retezec, offset):
    return encrypt(retezec, -offset)

if __name__ == "__main__":
encrypt("hey fellow how is it going", 5)
decrypt("mjd kjqqtb mtb nx ny ltnsl", 5)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this kind of situation, it's often better to write your code as a **class**. Your class's constructor could take just the minimum number of arguments that are *required* (which may be none at all!), and then optional arguments could be set as properties of the class or by using other methods.

When designing a class like this, I find it's most useful to **start by writing the client code first** -- that is, write the code that will **use** the class first, and then work backwards from there to design the class.

For example, I might want the code to look something like this:

```
cypher = Cypher()
cypher.offset = 17
cypher.set_alphabet('A', 'Z')
result = cypher.encrypt('hey fellow how is it going')
```

Hopefully it should be clear how to work from here to the design of the `Cypher` class, but if not, please ask a question on Stack Overflow about that!

If you want to provide `encrypt` and `decrypt` convenience methods, it's still easy to do. For example, you can write a function like:

```
def encrypt(text, offset):
    cypher = Cypher()
    cypher.offset = offset
    return cypher.encrypt(text)
```

Comment: Ah I see thanks a lot, I´ve just started with programming in Python at the school and I have writtten all my tasks in the functions only so far and I was not thinking about the Classes as in other languages. Thanks for your answer, I will try to write some simple classes to make the program looking better

Comment: @lukysuky: Glad to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I'll just leave [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078978/functional-programming-vs-object-oriented-programming) here.

Comment: @Art: Don't get me wrong, functional is a great paradigm (and far superior for many kinds of problems). But in Python where there's no built-in syntax for partial application, you end up with this problem of a combinatory explosion of arguments; I find objects to be the idiomatic way to solve that in this language. (If this question were about Haskell, my answer would be different, of course. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the docstring of `datetime.datetime`:

```
class datetime(date):
    """datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])
    ...
    """
```

And the signature of its constructor:

```
def __new__(cls, year, month=None, day=None, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None):
```

What we could learn from it:

- Add exactly as many arguments as it makes sense to add
- Use [parameters](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-parameter) and to give sensible default values to arguments

---

Side thought: do you think users of your library would should use `cycleencrypt()`? You could mark it private (with underscore), so everybody will see it's not a public API and they should use `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The number of arguments doesn't really matters as long as there are not a dozen of them (maybe someone can link to what you mention about having more than 3 arguments, I may be wrong).

To be more readable in the definition of a function, write comments by following [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) convention.

To be more readable at the call of a function, gives default values in the definition as much as possible for the more useful values (for example, offset can have the value 1 by default, and index 0).

Either way, for a long line, use [PEP8](http://pymbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pep8.html) guidelines which describes a way to jump lines correctly (the lines must not exceed 80 characters, according to [PEP8](http://pymbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pep8.html)).

```
def cycleencrypt(string, offset=1, index=0,
                     listing, first, last):
        """Description

        :param string: description
        :param offset: description
        :param index: description
        :param listing: description
        :param first: description
        :param last: description
        :return description
        """
        offset = offsetctrl(offset)
        if string >= ord(first) and string <= ord(last):
            string += offset
            while string > ord(last):
                string = ord(first) + (string - ord(last) - 1)
            listing[index] = chr(string)
```

Comment: I had some short docstrings around the functions following the pylint´s abilities but I deleted them here to make the code more visible for my purpose of this question

Comment: Ok :) I suggest to edit your question with that information, I see two of us answering to you about that.