# Comparing list values to items in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a dictionary of all states abbreviations as a key, and the long names as the value:

```
statesDict = {'AK': 'Alaska', 'AL': 'Alabama', 'AR': 'Arkansas',...}
```

I also have a list of pre-selected state abbreviations:

```
statesAbbrv = ['AL', 'CA', 'CO', 'DE']
```

Based on the items in the cleanStates list, I want to chose ***only*** the values (the long names) for the state abbreviations keys in the stateNames dictionary and place them in a new list; stateNames = []
So, the results of the comparison will look like this:

```
stateNames = ['Alabama', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Deleware']
```

I was thinking the following, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong here?

```
stateNames = []
for i in statesAbbrv:
    for k, v in statesDict:
        if stateDict[k] == stateAbbrv[i]:
            stateNames.append(stateDict(k))
print stateNames
```

Comment: `for i statesAbbrv:` is this Python code ? Do you mean `for i in statesAbbrv:`

Comment: `for i in statesAbbrv:`  You are missing `in`

Comment: Yes, i just forgot the 'in'. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stateNames = [stateDict[k] for k in statesAbbrv if k in stateDict]
```

using [`list comprehensions`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html).

Comment: This was the easiest and most direct solution. I will review list comprehension so that it is more obvious. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4):

Functionally<sup>1</sup>, you can use `map`<sup>2</sup> with `dict.get`:

```
stateNames = list(map(statesDict.get, statesAbbrv))
```

If no match is found for an abbreviation, this will give `None`. A stricter version which will yield `KeyError`:

```
stateNames = list(map(statesDict.__getitem__, statesAbbrv))
```

The latter is akin to the list comprehension, as `[]` is syntax to access `__getitem__`:

```
stateNames = [statesDict[i] for i in statesAbbrv]
```

If you wish to supply a fallback if a key is not found, use a list comprehension with `dict.get`:

```
stateNames = [statesDict.get(i, 'Fallback State') for i in statesAbbrv]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Functional programming is a style of programming that treats computation as the evaluation of mathematical functions. See also [Functional programming vs Object Oriented programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078978/functional-programming-vs-object-oriented-programming).

<sup>2</sup> In Python 2.x, explicit `list` conversion is not necessary since `map` returns a `list`. In Python 3, `map` returns an iterable, which will need to be exhausted via `list`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical job for a list comprehension:

```
stateNames = [statesDict.get(state, state) for state in statesAbbrv]
print(stateNames)
#['Alabama', 'CA', 'CO', 'DE']
```

Note that if a state abbreviation for some reason is not in the dictionary, it will be used as the state name itself.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the list `statesAbbrv` and lookup the values in `statesDict`

```
statesNames = [statesDict[n] for n in statesAbbrv]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stateNames = []
for i statesAbbrv:
    for k, v in statesDict.iteritems():
        if stateDict[k] == stateAbbrv[i]:
            stateNames.append(stateDict(k))
print stateNames
```

You need to add `iteritems()` to make the dictionary iterable on python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Serious typo errors in your question. Well, here is the answer (Just after removing errors in your own code):

```
statesDict = {'AK': 'Alaska', 'AL': 'Alabama', 'AR': 'Arkansas'}
statesAbbrv = ['AL', 'AK']

stateNames = []
for i in statesAbbrv:
    for k in statesDict.keys():
        if k == i:
            stateNames.append(statesDict[k])
print (stateNames)
```

Comment: this solution most closely aligns with the original code - but is terribly inefficient and verbose for a problem that should be solved directly.

Comment: Well before you comment or downvote, read CAREFULLY what the OP asked. He/She said "What am I doing wrong here?". So before you go downvoting, make sure you understand what OP wants. My answer was to tell him/her what he is doing wrong. Clearly, OP seems to be a beginner. So it's better to teach him/her what's goin wrong in his/her solution.

Comment: i completely agree, but along with that one should include the **right** way to do things - point taken tho

Comment: If everyone starts posting new "not so straightforward" solutions, how will a beginner learn and get to know what were the sources of error. I thought of doing something different rather than posting complicated (yet more efficient) solutions. If point is taken, I would ask to revert your vote in the spirit of my defense

Comment: the list comprehension is quite *readable* if that is the argument. i would call this *complicated*. Also SO does not allow it to be removed

Comment: That's not the argument. My argument was that I tried to answer what the OP was having errors with. Clearly, I don't want to have any more argument with you. Your downvote is fine with me. Period.

Answer (score 0):

```
stateNames = [statesDict.get(i) for i in statesAbbrv]
```