# How can I use Ramda's omit() function on a deeply nested object member in javascript

Tags: javascript, eval, javascript-objects, ramda.js

I have a situation where I want to remove any part of an object tree before flattening and exporting to CSV. [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) is my choice library for [FP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2079678/299708) in JS, but I noticed the `R.omit()` function works at only one level deep of the target object. How can I make it such that I can do the following?

```
const R = require('ramda');

const obj = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'me',
    audience_sizes: {
        fb: 500,
        dfp: 2000,
        apn: 1800
    }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(R.omit(['id', 'audience_sizes.fb'], obj)));
```

I would expect the following result:

```
{"name":"me","audience_sizes":{"dfp":2000, "apn": 1800}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DissocPath](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#dissocPath) look like what you are looking for. Use it or lenses for more complex deep updates.

Comment: Thanks. This greatly shortens my `omitDeep` function!

Answer (score 9):

I think [Lenses](http://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/07/12/thinking-in-ramda-lenses/) is a more functional way of doing this.

```
R.over(R.lensProp('audience_sizes'), R.omit(['fb']), R.omit(['id'], obj));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm new to Ramda, and I was not aware of this function. Can solve a lot of problems for me!