# Abstract function returning NULL instead of a string - PHP OOP

Tags: php, function, class, oop, abstract-class

I have this SessionService.php file that handles `session_start` and `session_regenerate_id` functions.

I make use of an abstract class that generates a new session ID and stores it in a variable called `$new_session_id`. Then I return this variable as an argument of an abstract function called `returnNewSessionID()`, contained in the class `SessionRegenerateID`. This abstract function is designed to return the variable `$new_session_id`.

That's where the problem is. **Instead of returning a string (the new session ID we generated), it returns NULL.**

At `createNewID()`, you see I am assigning the newly generated code to a session variable called `$_SESSION['new_session_id']`. By echoing this session variable, I get the expected value from it. At the same time, echoing the returned value from the `createNewID()` function gives me `NULL`.

The ID is being generated. The problem most likely lies in the way this variable `$new_session_id` is being used inside these functions. I need to figure out why it is not being returned by the abstract function.

*SessionService.php*

```php
interface SessionRegenerateInterface {

        public function createNewID();
        (... other unrelated functions ...)

}

abstract class AbstractSessionRegenerate implements SessionRegenerateInterface {

        public function createNewID() {
            $new_session_id = session_create_id();
            $_SESSION['new_session_id'] = $new_session_id;
            $this->returnNewSessionID($new_session_id);
        }

        abstract protected function returnNewSessionID($newID);

}

class SessionRegenerateID extends AbstractSessionRegenerate {

        protected function returnNewSessionID($newID) {
            return $newID;
        }

}
```

*SessionController.php*

```php
$RegenerateSession = new SessionRegenerateID;
$newID = $RegenerateSession->createNewID();
var_dump($newID);    // outputs NULL
var_dump($_SESSION['new_session_id']);    // outputs the generated session ID
```

I have an InputValidation class which is logically identical to this one, except for the type of value it returns: TRUE or FALSE. It works. But now that I am passing a variable with a string value, it returns NULL. I appreciate help to understand why.

Comment: `AbstractSessionRegenerate::createNewID` doesn't return anything. Adding `return` before `$this->returnNewSessionID($new_session_id);` should help :)

Comment: Thank you. It works. Such a simple thing :) So it seems the return is not needed when the value we are returning is a boolean. As I said at the end of the question, I have another abstract class that returns a bool value, and it works without return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jeto, I solved this by inserting a 'return' before `$this->returnNewSessionID($new_session_id);`

```
        public function createNewID() {
            $new_session_id = session_create_id();
            $_SESSION['new_session_id'] = $new_session_id;
            return $this->returnNewSessionID($new_session_id);
        }
```

Comment: The fact that it is a boolean or not doesn't matter. If you don't use `return`, your function won't return anything (or, more accurately, it will always return `null`).

Comment: I am pretty sure the boolean value is returned without using `return`. That's how I do InputValidation, and I echoed this to confirm. There is even an example where the value being returned is not even a boolean: [See the render() function inside the abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343881/9811172), so perhaps we're both missing something...?

Comment: @Doug if you want your function to return something, you *must* use the `return` keyword. Otherwise, it will return `NULL`: https://3v4l.org/5rUU1

Comment: @Doug The `render()` function in that example doesn't return anything, it writes something into the output using `echo`. Not the same thing. Note that the value isn't retrieved into any variable.

Comment: I ran var_dump() on my code again without 'return', and the output was NULL. I swear it did return bool(true) or bool(false) with the same code before. Maybe it's opcache's slow revalidate frequency. I am really surprised it didn't work this time. Thank you for the information, I edited the answer.